# How to create this type of popup dialogue in Android?

Tags: android, menu, popup, development-environment

This image took from Deep Relax app from Play Store:

[image: this image took from deep relax app from play store]

How do I create a popup menu? I am creating an app I want to ask the user to provide feedback?

Comment: use alert dialog, set positive,negative and neutral buttons

Comment: can you please be more specific. i just started android development. If it possible just post some helpful code.

Comment: You can spend more than 2 minutes figuring out a suggestion and googling some of the new terms you've just heard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this use custom dialog for this purpose:

Create layout like this custom_dialog_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="title"
    android:textColor="#000" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting," />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="description" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:id="@+id/btnNotNOw"
        android:text="not now"
        android:textColor="#040d28" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="Never"
        android:id="@+id/btnNever"
        android:textColor="#040d28" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="sure"
        android:id="@+id/btnSure"
        android:textColor="#040d28" />

</LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Now create dialog using below code:

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(LoginActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout);
    Button btnNotNOw, btnNever, btnSure;
    btnNotNOw = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnNotNOw);
    btnNever = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnNever);
    btnSure = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnSure);
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    window.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    dialog.show();

    btnNever.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           // perform your action here 
        }
    });
    btnNotNOw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           // perform your action here 
        }
    });
    btnSure.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           // perform your action here 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create  it by Custom Dialog :

**Custom Dialog :**

For this you have to create one `xml` file and have to attached.

```
final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(LabCheckOutActivity.this);
                dialog1.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog1.setCancelable(true);
                dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_patient_details);
                dialog1.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                // Setting Dialog Title
                alertDialog.setTitle("Top Heading");

                // Setting Dialog Message
                alertDialog.setMessage("Message");

                // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Sure", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // User pressed YES button. Write Logic Here
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on Sure",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                // Setting Negative "NO" Button
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Not Now", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // User pressed No button. Write Logic Here
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on Not Now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                // Setting Netural "Cancel" Button
                alertDialog.setNeutralButton("Never", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // User pressed Cancel button. Write Logic Here
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on Never",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                // Showing Alert Message
                alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this, AlertDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL);


            builder.setMessage("Positive,Negative and Neutral Button")


            builder.setCancelable(false);


            builder.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

            // Set the positive/yes button click listener
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                }
            });

            // Set the negative/no button click listener
            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });

            // Set the neutral/cancel button click listener
            builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            // Display the alert dialog on interface
            dialog.show();
```